# Functional Equation $f(f'(x))=-f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

Assume $f:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and satisfies $\forall x>0:f(f'(x))=-f(x)$. What is $f(x)$?

I know that $f(x)=\ln x$ is a solution, but I don't know if there is another one, or how can I prove that.

Comment: $\ln(x+C)$ for some arbitrary constant $C$ is a solution of this

Comment: It doesn't look like it is a solution... But how can I find all of the solutions?

Comment: @ASKASK you are wrong. Try any $C \neq 0$.

Comment: Oops, I made a small mistake

Comment: $f(x)$ is an increasing function because $f(f'(x))$ is defined if and only if $f'(x) >0.$

Comment: graph of $y = f(x)$ is concave down because $f^{\prime \prime}(x) = -\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f^\prime(f^\prime(x))}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the following.

Differentiate both parts of the equation:

$$f’(f’(x))f’’(x)=-f’(x).$$

Then $$f’(f’(x))=-\frac{f’(x)}{ f’’(x)}.$$

Take $f$ of both parts:

$$f(x)=-f(f’(x))=f(f’(f’(x)))=f\left(-\frac{f’(x)}{ f’’(x)}\right).$$

Since the function $f$ is injective,

$$x=-\frac{f’(x)}{ f’’(x)}.$$

This is a differential equation. Solve it

$$xf''(x)+f'(x)=0$$

$$\bigl(xf'(x)\bigr)'=0$$

$$xf'(x)=C_{1}$$

$$f(x)=C_{1}\ln x+C_{2}$$
The verification:

$$f(f’(x))=C_1\ln\left(\frac {C_1}x\right)+C_2=-(C_1\ln (x)+C_2).$$

So $C_2=-\frac{C_1\ln C_1}2$ and

$$f(x)=\frac{\ln Kx}{K^2}.$$

PS. In general, we cannot a priori assume that $f$ is twice differentiable. For instance, consider a similar situation. Let $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a function such that $g(x)=x^2$ if  $x\ge 0$ and $g(x)=-x^2$ if  $x< 0$. Then $g’(x)=|x|$, $g(g’(x))=x^2$ is a differentiable function, but $g’’(0)$ does not exist. So a question remains open for a not twice differentiable function $f$.

Comment: (It should be noted that by hypothesis $f'>0$, so that $f$ is injective as you say)

Comment: looks very nice.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff This is already [noted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096885/functional-equation-ffx-fx/1112122#comment2235777_1096885) by Alex Silva. A bigger problem is: why we can apply a formula of derivative of a composition to the left part of the equation?

Comment: @AlexRavsky How did you get from $x=-\frac{f'(x)}{f''(x)}$ to $xf''(x)+f(x)=0$?

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret It was not me. :-) My answer was edited by Panja.S., who had a good intention but a less attention. :-) I fixed this.